# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException seems to be holding up future threads

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a Swing application that displays a file system with a JTree. When you double-click a file, the contents are supposed to be displayed in a JTextArea within a JTabbedPane. I have a custom SwingWorker which seems to do things correctly for small files, but not for large ones.

I believe I'm using the EDT correctly. In doInBackground(), I append each line of the clicked file to a string and return it so get() can use it. In done(), I append the string to a JTextArea and then add that to the JTabbedPane.

With a large file, I get this exception at the very end of reading the lines. After this error, I can't open any more files. In the thread dump, I see new SwingWorker threads being created but they are waiting for the ThreadPoolExectuor to do something. I'm sure it's related to this exception but not sure how. The error occurs in the DataBufferInt constructor when making the data array. It looks related to making an image but I'm not using any images.

```
public DataBufferInt(int size) {
        super(STABLE, TYPE_INT, size);
        data = new int[size];
        bankdata = new int[1][];
        bankdata[0] = data;
    }
```

Exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(DataBufferInt.java:75)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:467)
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1032)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:351)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaPainter$AquaSingleImagePainter.createImage(AquaPainter.java:193)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaPainter$AquaSingleImagePainter.lambda$paintFromSingleCachedImage$0(AquaPainter.java:178)
    at sun.awt.image.MultiResolutionCachedImage.getResolutionVariant(MultiResolutionCachedImage.java:66)
    at sun.awt.image.MultiResolutionCachedImage.getBaseImage(MultiResolutionCachedImage.java:106)
    at sun.awt.image.AbstractMultiResolutionImage.getWidth(AbstractMultiResolutionImage.java:82)
    at sun.awt.image.MultiResolutionCachedImage.getWidth(MultiResolutionCachedImage.java:89)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(SunGraphics2D.java:3262)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(SunGraphics2D.java:3214)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaPainter$AquaSingleImagePainter.paintFromSingleCachedImage(AquaPainter.java:186)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaPainter$AquaSingleImagePainter.paint(AquaPainter.java:141)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaPainter.paint(AquaPainter.java:90)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaGroupBorder.paintBorder(AquaGroupBorder.java:68)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaTabbedPaneUI.paintContentBorder(AquaTabbedPaneUI.java:661)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaTabbedPaneUI.paint(AquaTabbedPaneUI.java:134)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Thread dump.

```
"SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-3" #27 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007feffb972800 nid=0x7103 waiting on condition [0x000070000f827000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c04f3c08> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-2" #25 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff00100a000 nid=0x73df waiting on condition [0x000070000f51e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c04f3c08> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"TimerQueue" #24 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007ff0008e2000 nid=0x11817 waiting on condition [0x000070000f724000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c04e5470> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:211)
        at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(TimerQueue.java:174)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000006c04f7100> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)

"SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1" #23 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007feffb930800 nid=0x727b waiting on condition [0x000070000f621000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c04f3c08> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"JMX server connection timeout 21" #21 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007feffc281800 nid=0x7b07 in Object.wait() [0x000070000f41b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java:168)
        - locked <0x00000006c01c96e0> (a [I)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"RMI Scheduler(0)" #20 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007feffca02000 nid=0x7a0f waiting on condition [0x000070000f318000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c01d47e0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

Here is a section of the code. I wasn't sure how to re-create this on a smaller scale but hopefully you get the idea of what it's doing. I have a MouseAdapter (or Listener?) that gets called on a double-click. If the node (file) is not a directory, execute the Swing Worker to gather the contents of the file line by line and then append to a JTextField.

```
    class TreeMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {

                TreeNode selectedNode = (TreeNode) fileSystem.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

                File f;
                if (!(f = selectedNode.getFile()).isDirectory()) {

                    new openFileWorker(f).execute();

                }

            }

        }

    }

    class openFileWorker extends SwingWorker<String, Void> {

        File file;

        public openFileWorker(File f) {
            super();
            file = f;

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            String line;
            String output = "";

            if (!"gz".equals(getFileExtension(this.file.getAbsolutePath()))) {

                try {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        output = output + line + "\n";
                    }
                    System.out.println(output);
                    return output;

                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DossierView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DossierView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } finally {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(DossierView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

            } else {

                try {
                    GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(this.file.getAbsolutePath()));
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gzip));
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        //System.out.println(line);
                        //fileText.append(line + "\n");
                        output = output + line + "\n";
                    }

                    return output;

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DossierView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } finally {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(DossierView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void done() {

            try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                String text = (String) get();
                JTextArea fileText = new JTextArea();
                fileText.append(text);
                tabPane.add(this.file.getName().split("\\.")[0], fileText);

            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DossierView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you make a call to `new DataBufferInt()`? That constructor is being passed a negative value, so `data = new int[size]` is throwing your exception. Arrays must have 0 or more elements. Locate that call and your problem is solved.

Comment: I'm not calling it myself and don't know where it's coming from other than the EDT.